# SRP- Princípio da Responsabilidade Única

Tags: c#, solid

Na classe Pedido, que contêm as regras de negócio para solicitar um pedido de venda, informe qual das opções abaixo viola o principio da responsabilidade única (**SRP**- Single Responsibility Principle)?

- Pedido.AdicionarItem():
- Pedido.AplicarDesconto();
- Pedido.SalvarDados();
- Pedido.ReprogramarEntrega();
- Pedido.Cancelar();

Comment: Fechei como ampla porque sem saber os requisitos não tem como saber. Note que as duas respostas postadas interpretam de forma diferente, porque a pergunta dá margem para isto. Eu poderia responder que `SalvarDados()` é que viola e estaria certo em certo ponto de vista.

Answer (score 2):

SRP - Princípio da Responsabilidade Única

*Single Responsibility Principle (SRP), ou, Princípio da Responsabilidade Única. Esse princípio diz que as classes devem ser coesas, ou seja, terem uma única responsabilidade. Classes assim tendem a ser mais reutilizáveis, mais simples, e propagam menos mudanças para o resto do sistema.*

Portanto:

- Adicionar Item
- Aplicar Desconto
- Salvar Dados
- Reprogramar Entrega
- Cancelar

O método **Cancelar** faz parte do pedido.

O método **AplicarDesconto** faz parte do pedido.

O método **SalvarDados** faz parte do pedido, desde que seja especificamente do pedido.

O método **AdicionaItem** faz parte do pedido, desde que seja especificamente do pedido.

**ReprogramarEntrega** viola, esse método deveria ser dentro da classe de entrega, com o pedido relacionado, e não dentro do pedido.

Answer (score -1):

Então, pela minha experiência e a maneira pela qual eu tenho trabalhado, eu 
criaria 3 objetos. Pedido, PedidoRepositorio e PedidoServico, e assim deixaria uma responsábilidade para cada uma e também ja usaria o padrão Repository.

Pedido -> Seria o model, apenas com as propriedades a serem salvas;

```
   -> AdicionarItem(PedidoItem -> Seria uma outra classe para os itens e 
      ficaria como uma propriedade do tipo List na classe Pedido)
```

PedidoRepositorio -> Seria o objeto responsável por persistir no banco de dados;

```
   -> SalvarDados(Pedido)
   -> Cancelar(idPedido)
   -> AplicarDesconto(idPedido, valorDesconto)
   -> ReprogramarEntrega(idPedido)
```

PedidoServico -> (Camada responsável pela validação dos dados antes de chamar a
                  classe de repositorio, é ela quem comunica com a repositorio e 
                  a UI.)

```
   -> SalvarDados(Pedido)
   -> Cancelar(idPedido)
   -> AplicarDesconto(idPedido, valorDesconto)
   -> ReprogramarEntrega(idPedido)
```

Comment: -1 Matheus a pergunta é sobre Single Responsibility Principle, logo reprogramarEntrega não faz parte do pedido, assim como o tiago respondeu.

Comment: Concordo, por isto minha classe é PedidoServico, ela tem a responsablidade da salvar o pedido, cancelar, aplicar desconto, reprogramar a entrega do pedido, esta é a sua responsabilidade. Por isso cada camada tem uma responsabilidade, a camada repositorio de fazer o crud, a camada de serviço de validar os dados e chamar a repositorio e a classe pedido que é o modelo.